Dell 5491 USB-C suddenly stopped accepting power
The problem
I have a Dell 5491 laptop which I could charge using its USB-C port. However, about two weeks ago, it suddenly stopped working.
The USB-C port also has DisplayPort capabilities, and that still works properly. It can still transfer data and if plug a monitor into it that has a mouse and keyboard connected, they work. The normal barrel charger still works fine.
What's weird is that if I first plug a USB-C cable and then the barrel plug, it won't charge as I assume it still thinks it takes its power from the USB-C port.
Things that I have tried
Tried using other USB-C cables. Updating and reinstalling the USB Windows Driver. Booting into Ubuntu to see if it's a problem with Windows. Unplugging and plugging the battery back in. Resetting BIOS to Factory Settings and Default settings. Running BIOS diagnostic scan, which turned out nothing wrong.
None of this worked.
Questions
What might have went wrong and what could be possible fixes that I haven't tried? I attempted to take a picture of the port to see if any pin has been broken, but I can't really see too well.
